# Javascript error, help please

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out why this is happening.

```
http://www.freemoviedb.com/watch/5749/28_weeks_later.html
```

Click the thumb up / thumb down, it doesn't do anything but load.

In firebug, all it says is:

```
invalid 'in' operand a
http://static.freemoviedb.com/thumbsup/init.min.js.php
Line 1
```

/

```
invalid 'in' operand a
error(Object { name="a"})init.min.js.php (line 1)
b()jquery.min.js (line 124)
abort(Object { name="q"})
```

Comment: The code is minified. Get an unminified version before you bother trying to debug it. That way line numbers will be more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it breaks is the response, because of it being another domain, is `null` (thanks to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)), so this part:

```
success: function (a) {
  if ('error' in a) { //here's your error
```

...fails, because the data from the response (`a`) will be `null` on a cross-domain request, and `("anything" in null)` will throw the error you're seeing.

Comment: What do you suggest me to do to fix this?

Comment: @Kyle - Your voting page needs to be on the same domain, `www.freemoviedb.com` rather than `static.freemoviedb.com`, or make it a JSONP request, either one's an option...though the JSONP has some security issues, better to go with the same domain.

Comment: @Kyle - you have `url: g + 'init.php',`...whatever `g` is in the full version, that `g` refers to `var g = 'http://static.freemoviedb.com/thumbsup/';`, instead of using it in your `url`, actually use the `www.` domain there.

Comment: Okay, will fix it up tomorrow and move this particular script back to the original domain. Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see right away is that your Ajax request is going cross-domain and it seems to be generating a preceding error

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://static.freemoviedb.com/thumbsup/init.php. Origin http://www.freemoviedb.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

`www.xyz.com` is different than `static.xyz.com`

This may be why the remaining code is failing

Comment: Its because I just changed my images, js and css to a static cookieless domain, how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: I think this is answered in the above response. Good luck!